# Minimum hardware requirements to run an HTML5 capable browser

Tags: html, browser, hardware, minimum-requirements

Which is the browser with minimum hardware requirements with full support to HTML5?
The application should be able to play videos and perform some javascript transformations.

Windows or Linux it doesn't matter (but I bet my two cents on Linux as the winner).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's custom hardware very similar to a PC.

Answer (score -1):

You may be putting the cart before the horse here.

There are a lot of "post pc" devices out there that have very low hardware specifications (iPod/iPad/iPhone, various Android devices, Blackberries, Windows Mobile Devices) that can run lightweight, full featured HTML5 browsers based on projects like WebKit (webkit.org).

Answer (score -1):

Following browsers supports HTML5 for better client rendering especially when having flash, video streaming and mobile version of site. browsers: IE 10, Google chrome, Opera, netscape navigator.